# Name is getting mangled by Webpack 5 while mini-css-extract-plugin loader

Tags: bundler, bootstrap-5, webpack-5

Trying to export scss file with bootstrap 5.2 to a css file and linking that file to a index.php file but class names i guess are getting mangled somehow so I can't use bootstrap class like for a button `btn btn-primary`, as the generated classes names are like `GcpZ2uTclIsK3IUwa3qT XWJXtmqteXQMN_oydssO`

I have tried many webpack config but unable to find a solution. My current configs are shared below.
how can I use bootstrap exported scss in webpack build ?

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: "./src/js/main.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      linkType: "text/css",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: () => [require("autoprefixer")],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

#### styles.scss

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

#### main.js

```
import "../scss/styles.scss";
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
import {addNumber} from './sum'
import {divideNumbers} from './division'
import {buttonClickAction} from './events'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so new to webpack so I didn't exactly know what was I doing wrong.
The problem was in webpack config file `css-loader` as bootstrap works with global css selector not module based i had to remove

```
{
 options: {
  modules: true,
 },
},
```